# Class of function that satisfies $\| f\|_p^p = \|f\|_q^q$ for all finite $q,p\ge1$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the class of functions $f$ on a measure space $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ that satisfy $\|f\|_p^p = \|f\|_q^q$ for all finite $q$, $p\ge1$. Which functions are contained in this set?

Comment: Possible start: if $|f| > 1 + \epsilon$ on some set $E$ of positive measure, then $\lVert f \rVert_p^p \ge (1 + \epsilon)^p \mu(E) \to \infty$ as $p \to \infty$, which makes it impossible for $\lVert f \rVert_p^p$ to be a finite constant.  Therefore, if $\lVert f \rVert_p^p$ is a finite constant, then $|f| \le 1$ a.e.

Comment: You should certainly need the eventual conclusion to be $f = 0$ or $|f| = 1$ a.e. - since $\chi_A$ satisfies the condition for any measurable $A$ of finite measure.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Your last claim is not true.

Comment: @amsmath Why not? $\lVert \chi_A \rVert_p^p = \int |\chi_A|^p \, d\mu = \int \chi_A \, d\mu = \mu(A)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, you are right. Forgot that we don't take the power $1/p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\in\mathcal F$ (I assume that $\|f\|_p = \operatorname{const} < \infty$). Let us first prove that $|f|\le 1$ (a.e.). This is due to Daniel Schepler (see the comments above). Let $A_n := \{|f|\ge 1+1/n\}$, $n\in\mathbb N$. Then
$$
\|f\|_p^p\ge\int_{A_n}(1+1/n)^p\,d\mu\ge (1+1/n)^p\mu(A_n).
$$
Since this tends to $\infty$ if $\mu(A_n) > 0$ (as $p\to\infty$), we conclude that $\mu(A_n) = 0$. Now, $\mu(\{|f| > 1\}) = \mu(\bigcup_nA_n) = 0$, so that indeed $|f|\le 1$ a.e. Hence, $|f|^2\le|f|$. Define the set $A := \{|f|^2 < |f|\}$. If $\mu(A) > 0$, then
$$
\int|f|^2\,d\mu = \int_{A}|f|^2\,d\mu + \int_{|f|^2=|f|}|f|^2\,d\mu < \int|f|\,d\mu,
$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore, $|f|^2 = |f|$ a.e., that is, $|f|(1-|f|) = 0$ a.e., which implies that $|f|$ takes only values in $\{0,1\}$. Thus, $|f| = \chi_A$ for some $A\in\mathcal E$ with $\mu(A) < \infty$ (as $f\in L^1$).

Comment: And if $E$ has infinite measure?  In that case, you might replace $\mu(E \setminus A)$ with $\int_{E \setminus A} |f|^1 \, d\mu$.  So, this implies $\int_E |f|^p d\mu \le \int_{E \setminus A} |f| d\mu + \epsilon \le \lVert f \rVert_1^1 + \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $p$, and the assumption together with this implies that $f = 0$ a.e. on $A$.

Comment: Or: by the dominated convergence theorem, if $A = \{ x : |f(x)| = 1 \}$, then $|f|^p \to \chi_A$ pointwise a.e., so $\lVert f \rVert_p^p \to \mu(A)$ as $p \to \infty$, and on the other hand $\lVert f \rVert_1^1 = \mu(A) + \int_{E \setminus A} |f| \, d\mu$, so $\int_{E \setminus A} |f| \, d\mu = 0$ implying $f = 0$ a.e. on $E \setminus A$.

Comment: Oh wait, you should be fine too with just a short mention that $\mu(E \setminus A) \le \lVert f \rVert_1^1$ is finite.

Comment: Hmm... unless $\mu(A)$ is infinite - very possible if $E$ is an infinite measure space and $f$ is the indicator function of a finite-measure set...

Comment: If you refine to $A = \{ 0 < |f| \le 1 - \epsilon \}$ and $B = \{ 1 - \epsilon < |f| \}$ (then use $B$ in place of $E \setminus A$) then $f \in L^1$ implies $A$ is $\sigma$-finite and $\mu(B) < \infty$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I edited my answer. Have a new argument.

Comment: Looks good. So, all we *really* need to make the argument work is: $\liminf_{p\to \infty} \lVert f \rVert_p^p < \infty$ (for proving $|f| \le 1$ a.e.) and $\lVert f \rVert_p^p = \lVert f \rVert_q^q$ for some pair $1 \le p < q$ (for an easy generalization of your finishing argument).

Comment: Feel free to incorporate the text of my argument into your answer with attribution, just in case the comments are moved or expire some time in the future.

Comment: Ok, edited it.. Let us delete all our comments below the answer cause they don't refer to nothing anymore. Except your comment with $\liminf$